# Returned image of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE has only one size?

Tags: android

I call Intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MENU_COVER_PHOTO_TAKE);
            InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtName.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

and get bitmap by:

```
bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

but when i check, it has one size 480x360.
And when i take image by capturing in landscape mode, image is OK, but in portrait, image's auto rorate and it doesn't keep aspect ratio.
Please help me fix it. Thank you very much.
My device: SONY IS12S, android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting only the thumbnail of your picture if you don't provide the path of a temp file.

Fix your code with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, MENU_COVER_PHOTO_TAKE);
```

More detail on:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html